# Многоточие в регулярных выражениях

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Не выходит заставить регулярное выражение принимать только точку. В строке присутствует как точка так и многоточие(при чем как в первом так и во втором случае возможны "лишние" пробелы): `Это строка... Это строка . Это строка.`. Многоточие нахожу так: `"\\s*\\.{3}\\s*"`. После чего пытаюсь найти и заменить все точки так: `"\\s*\\.{1}\\s*"`. В результате получаю то что последнее выражение находит точки одиночные и в многоточиях. Как исключить многоточия для данного выражения?

Comment: Пишите более развернутые и подробные вопросы с примерами и то, что уже есть.

Comment: Попробуйте ``"\\s*(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)\\s*"``

Comment: @And, кода не мало. Попытался обьяснить все сжато.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, верно..опишите в ответе как это работает если вам не тяжело.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать блоки предварительного просмотра вперед и назад, чтобы найти только те точки, перед и за которыми нет других точек:

```
"\\s*(?<!\\.)\\.(?!\\.)\\s*"
```

Тут `(?<!\.)` находит совпадение, если сразу перед точкой нет другой точки, а `(?!\.)` проверяет, нет ли точки после точки, которая находится с помощью шаблона  `\.`.

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/XiI3jV/1/).